# SSIS write variables to log

Tags: variables, logging, ssis

I am trying to capture the value of a variable in SSIS package and send to log.
Specifically, when I go into the SSIS Catalog, select my project and package, right click and choose Reports...Standard reports...All executions I would like to see value of variable there, if possible.

Otherwise, I need some log to send value of variable to.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to capture the value of a variable in your SSIS package, you can use a `Script Task` component.
Open the `Script Task Editor` and select `ReadWriteVariables` in the `Script Language` section and click the `Edit Script` button.

For example, you can use C# to achieve this :

```
string MyVariable = (string) Dts.Variables["NameOfYourVariable"].Value;
Dts.Log("The value of my variable is " + MyVariable, 0, null);
```

Try to execute and the Script Task component will capture the value of the variable and send it to the log
You can check the log by right-clicking the package in the "SSIS Packages" folder in SSMS > "Reports" > "All Executions".